# Facebook post to wall with audience selector using graph api

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have written this code in Objective-C

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>

#import "CustomLoginViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation CustomLoginViewController

- (IBAction)buttonTouched:(id)sender
{

    if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpen
        || FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended) {

        [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];

    } else {

        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"] defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceOnlyMe allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {

            __block NSString *alertText;
            __block NSString *alertTitle;
            if (!error) {
                if ([FBSession.activeSession.permissions
                     indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] == NSNotFound){
                    // Permission not granted, tell the user we will not publish
                    alertTitle = @"Permission not granted";
                    alertText = @"Your action will not be published to Facebook.";
                    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:alertTitle
                                                message:alertText
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK!"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
                } else {
                    // Permission granted, publish the OG story
                    //                                                    [self publishStory];
                    NSLog(@"Publish permission granted !");
                    [self publishPOST];
                }

            } else {
                // There was an error, handle it
                // See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors/
            }


            // Retrieve the app delegate
            AppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
            // Call the app delegate's sessionStateChanged:state:error method to handle session state changes
            [appDelegate sessionStateChanged:session state:status error:error];
        }];
    }//else
}
- (IBAction)post:(id)sender {

}
-(void)publishPOST{
    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"Description goes here.",@"description",
                                   @"www.google.com/image.jpg",@"picture",
                                   @"www.google.com/invites/username", @"link",
                                   @"Google",@"name",
                                   @"www.google.com",@"caption",
                                   nil];

    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"published !");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"published Failed ??");
        }
    }];

}

@end
```

but the problem is that i want to post with FBSessionDefaultAudienceNone,
FBSessionDefaultAudienceOnlyMe,FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends and FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone by programmatically.

I have written FBSessionDefaultAudienceOnlyMe to post as only me, It doesn't work for me. 
On the other hand it post as Friends.
Please any one help me to post as only me and Everyone programmatically.
If i am going wrong then please guide me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this code this may will help you

```
- (void)postData:(NSString *)message url:(NSURL *)url thumbnail:(NSURL *)thumbnail audience:(SocialNetworkAudience)audience
{        
    NSString* privacy;
    switch (audience) {
        case SocialNetworkAudiencePrivate:
            privacy = @"SELF";
            break;
        case SocialNetworkAudienceProtected:
            privacy = @"ALL_FRIENDS";
            break;
        case SocialNetworkAudiencePublic:
            privacy = @"EVERYONE";
            break;
    }

    [FBRequestConnection
        startWithGraphPath:@"/me/feed"
        parameters:@{
            @"description": message,
            @"link": url.absoluteString,
            @"picture": thumbnail.absoluteString,
            @"privacy": @"{'value': 'SELF'}"
        }
        HTTPMethod:@"POST"
        completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        }
    ];
}
```

This will post to your feed in facebook.

for other audiences you have to get value of privacy in place of 'SELF' here in this line.

```
@"privacy": @"{'value': 'SELF'}"
```